# Some keypress events doesn't work on Tampermonkey.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I have a javascript function which does something on `onkeypress`. I'm using Tampermonkey for Chrome and when I press the key I assigned, the function doesn't fire. In Greasemonkey instead, I have no problem with this.

Here is my code :

```
var names=["Aries Virgo Leo","John Steve Bill Sarah","Keny Ben Lovendal"];
var i = 1;

window.onkeypress = function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 113){ // the F2 key 
    document.getElementsByClassName("post-text-area")[0].value = names[0];
    document.getElementsByClassName("cmnt-btn")[0].click();


var repeat = setInterval(function start(){
if(i == names.length -1)clearInterval(repeat);
document.getElementsByClassName("reply")[0].click();
document.getElementsByClassName("post-text-area")[1].value = names[i];
document.getElementsByClassName("cmnt-btn")[1].click(); 
i++;
  },2000);}};
```

I don't know why Chrome doesn't accept key events like F1-F12, Tab, Ctrl, Delete, Insert etc. Is it possible to change this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>F2</kbd> can't be caught with keypress. You should use either keydown or keyup.

Tried with Tampermonkey, it works.